# Big O Notation queries

Tags: algorithm, big-o

```
int k = n;
while (k > 0)
{
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
 System.out.println(“Inside the inner loop”);
 }
k = k / 2;
 }
```

Hi for this question, I came up with two answers, that is

O (N^2 Log N) OR O (n * N/2) = O (N2/2). I'm not sure if there are the same or different? My lecturer also mentioned to chose the upper case. Therefore, for this question, there are one O(N^2) and one O(Log N). So the answer should be O(N^2) according to my lecturer? please help. Thanks.

Comment: Any of these answers are wrong. Read your materials again.

Comment: Number of iteration is directly proportional to N^2 Log N (while loop will run for n/2 times; and for each while count for loop will run for n times). If n=10, loop will run for 50 times; if n=1000000 loop will run 500000 times. is the explanation correct?

Comment: No. Where did you get this `N^2` from?

Comment: It will be O(n * log n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `O(N * log N)`

Since you divide `K` in halfes you get `O(log N)` for outer loop. And since in each iteration you iterate `N` times then it will be `O(N * log N)`.